# Adjusting the position of labels when drawing a diagram using feynmf

Tags: labels, feynmf

When drawing a Feynman diagram using `feynmf`, I'm having a hard time to place the labels in such a way that they do not overlap with each other and/or touch lines.

Here is one attempt:

```
\begin{fmffile}{fmflabels}
\parbox{16mm}{
\begin{fmfgraph*}(16,16)
\fmfleft{ve}
\fmfright{vo}
\fmftop{v}
\fmffreeze
\fmfforce{(0w,0.5h)}{ve}
\fmfforce{(1.0w,0.5h)}{vo}
\fmfforce{(.5w,0.1h)}{v}
\fmffreeze
\fmf{plain,left=0.8,label=$1$,l.s=left,l.d=0.01w}{ve,vo}
\fmf{plain,left=0.8}{vo,ve}
\fmf{plain,left=0.5,label=$2$,l.s=left,l.d=0.05h-0.05w}{v,vo}
\fmf{plain,left=0.5,label=$1/2$,l.s=left,l.d=0.05h-0.05w}{ve,v}
\fmf{phantom,right=0.1,label=$1$,l.s=left}{vo,v}
\fmf{phantom,right=0.1,label=$1$}{ve,v}
\fmffreeze
\fmfdot{ve,v,vo}
\end{fmfgraph*}
}
\end{fmffile}
```

Here is the output: [image]

The labels are not placed correctly as they overlap with the lines.
Other attempts (with different values in `label.distance`) did not improve the result. So there is something I do not understand about `label.distance` and placing labels.

Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this? And how to systematically place the label at the desired position?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here: (a) you are trying to make it so small that there's no room for the labels, (b) you are trying to force the positions when you don't need to.

Here's a simplified version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{fmflabels}
\resizebox{25.4mm}{!}{
\begin{fmfgraph*}(120,120)
%\fmfleft{ve}
%\fmfright{vo}
%\fmftop{v}
%\fmffreeze
\fmfforce{(0w,0.5h)}{ve}
\fmfforce{(1.0w,0.5h)}{vo}
\fmfforce{(.5w,0.1h)}{v}
%\fmffreeze
\fmf{plain,left=0.8,label=$1a$}{ve,vo}
\fmf{plain,left=0.3,label=$1/2$}{ve,v}
\fmf{plain,right=0.3,label=$1c$}{ve,v}
\fmf{plain,left=0.3,label=$2$}{v,vo}
\fmf{plain,right=0.3,label=$1b$}{v,vo}
%\fmffreeze
\fmfdot{ve,v,vo}
\end{fmfgraph*}
}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

### Notes

- I've added the suffixes `a`, `b`, and `c` just to make it more obvious which label is which
- I've increased the size of the graph to 120x120 so that we have some room to breathe, and then scaled the whole thing down with `\resizebox` from the standard `graphics` package.
- I've used `feynmp-auto` package to simplify compiling the whole thing
- I've commented out the redundant definitions of the nodes at the start.
- You don't need any of the `\fmffreeze` lines since you are using `\fmfforce` to place all three nodes.
- I've removed all of the label position hints and just let them take their default places; the important thing is to get the order of the nodes consistent with the side-to-side deflection of the connections.
- I don't think you can pass expressions to the label distance options, I think it will only read a number, so all of your expressions were being read as "0"
- I scaled the whole thing down to 1 inch which makes it just about readable.  You might find it a bit too small at 16mm.